# Filter relationship in rails json api using many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have these models:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :account_members
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy

end
```

and

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :project_members, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class ProjectMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :account_member
end
```

and

```
class AccountMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :project_members, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My account's controller index function

```
  def index
    @accounts = @current_user.accounts

    render json: @accounts, include: params[:include]
  end
```

The problem is this action returns the accounts with all projects BUT the user might only be a member of 2 projects.  I want it to return only projects that the user has access to through the project_members relationship.

How do you do that?

**EDIT 1** I am also using cancancan if that makes a difference.

**EDIT 2** This is the account serializer

```
class AccountSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :users
  has_many :account_members
  has_many :invites
  has_many :projects
  has_many :clients
end
```

Comment: I am also using cancancan if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use cancancan you can filter it through ability
in AccountSerializer

```
has_many :projects do
  ability = Ability.new(scope)
  @object.projects.select{ |p| ability.can?(:read, p) }
end
```